# Getting an error while am trying to run gatsby-starter-ghost project

Tags: javascript, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

When I try to run the project, it just shows this error nothing more than this and am stuck in it.

I have downloaded a starter pack from gatsby template : https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/TryGhost/gatsby-starter-ghost
This is the link of that starter pack, I just downloaded and tried to run the project but it's showing this error

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this....
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also: don’t upload images with errors. Put the error in your question as text. See: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Am encountering the same issue just doesn't seem to find a way to get out of the error